# Variable subtraction in django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

It is able to write `{{ myval.add:5 }}`, `{{ myval|add:value }}` and even `{{ myval|add:-5 }}`.

However, I can't find out what I should type to add value * -1 like `{{ myval|add:-value }}`. This doesn't work, sadly.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

The built-in Django template tags/filters aren't all-encompassing, but it's super easy to write your own custom template tags: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/

You could make your own `subtract` template tag pretty easily:

```
@register.filter
def subtract(value, arg):
    return value - arg
```

Comment: no need of a template tag for such a task. See Simeon's answer.

Comment: Simeon's answer does not answer the question, as it relates to subtracting by an amount defined in a variable.

Answer (score 153):

You need to use double quotes:

```
{{ myval|add:"-5" }}
```

This subtracts five from `myval`.

Comment: I need to subtract value from variable.

Comment: Is it possible to make the value negative in the view instead of in the template?

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to build a subtract filter all this time and this is even easier haha

Comment: This isn't a good answer. I need to subtract a variable from a variable. If I have `x == 5` and `y == 2`, how do I express `x - y` in a template?

Comment: @GershomMaes create a templatetag to receive as argument the number you want to subtract. `myval|subtract:anotherval`

Comment: Ok, thanks! I was just trying to figure out if the only way to do this was with a custom templatetag.

Comment: this is pretty much the worst way I have seen to do something as simple as a substract. Not your fault, but django templating language? what happened

Answer (score 29):

Use `django-mathfilters` from PyPI: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters

To install :

```
$ pip install django-mathfilters
```

Then add `mathfilters` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

In template:

```
{% load mathfilters %}

<ul>
    <li>8 + 3 = {{ 8|add:3 }}</li>

    <li>13 - 17 = {{ 13|sub:17 }}</li>

    {% with answer=42 %}
    <li>42 * 0.5 = {{ answer|mul:0.5 }}</li>
    {% endwith %}

    {% with numerator=12 denominator=3 %}
    <li>12 / 3 = {{ numerator|div:denominator }}</li>
    {% endwith %}

    <li>|-13| = {{ -13|abs }}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: These should be included in the main Django distribution, in my opinion.

Comment: you need to add `mathfilters` to your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Answer (score 5):

I recently started working with Django and stumbled upon this one as well: I needed a very simple template loop that stops printing after n times and shows a "more" link to toggle the rest of the items.

With great interest I read the struggle of people trying to understand why this is not being added to the Django default filters (since before 2013).  I didn't feel like creating a custom template tag and I kind of found a way to subtract 2 variables using strings and `add` in combination with `with` and `stringformat`

Let's say I have a list of items where I want to print the first 2 and hide the rest, showing how many hidden items are there, eg.

John, Anna and 5 others like this (when given a list of 7 items)

As long as the number of visible items is harcoded in the template (eg. 2), it's possible to add the negative 2 `|add:"-2"`, but I wanted the number of visible items to be a variable as well.  The Math-filter library as suggested above doesn't seem up to date (I haven't tested it with Django 2.x).

The trick seems to be to use the `add` helper to concat the strings "-" with the integer as string, so it can be coerced back to a negative integer in a any consecutive calls to the `add` helper.  This doesn't work however if the value is not a string, so that's where the `stringformat` helper comes in.

#### With string value

template `posts.html` (note how `visible` is explicitely passed as string - alternative below)

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
  ...
  {% include 'show_likes.html' with likes=post.likes visible="3" %}
{% endfor %}
```

template `show_likes.html` (note the `add:0` to make the boolean operator work)

```
{% with show=visible|default:"2" %}
{% for like in likes %}
  {% if forloop.counter <= show|add:0 %}
    {% if not forloop.first %},{% endif %}
    {{ like.username }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if likes|length > show|add:0 %}
{% with rest="-"|add:show %}
  and {{ likes|length|add:rest }} more
{% endwith %}
{% endif %}
like this
{% endwith %}
```

#### Alternative with integer

*You could just convert your integer to a string in the calling template using `|stringformat:"d"`*

If however the number of visible items you want to show is an integer, you'll have to add a call to stringformat:"d" to have it converted to string

template `posts.html`

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <h4>{{ post.title }}</h4>
  ...
  {% include 'show_likes.html' with likes=post.likes visible=3 %}
{% endfor %}
```

template `show_likes.html`

```
{% with show=visible|default:2 %}
{% with show_str=show|stringformat:"d" %}
{% for like in likes %}
  {% if forloop.counter <= show %}
    {% if not forloop.first %},{% endif %}
    {{ like.username }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if likes|length > show|add:0 %}
{% with rest="-"|add:show_str %}
  and {{ likes|length|add:rest }} more
{% endwith %}
{% endif %}
{% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

Since I'm a very beginner with Django and Python, I'm pretty sure this approach is far worse than actually creating a custom helper!  So I'm not suggesting anyone should be using this.  This was just my attempt on trying to solve this with the available template helpers and without any custom stuff.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Lo primero es multiplicar por -1 para convertirlo en una valor negativo y guardarlo en una variable y posterior a usar la suma

> The first thing is to multiply by -1 to turn it into a negative value
> and save it in a variable and then use the add

```
{% widthratio val2 1 -1 as result %}
{{result|add:val1}}
```

Answer (score -1):

After search I found that I can make `{% with var=value %}` with *filters* to make the arithmetic operations ***"with other variables or not"***

For example: I have `x = 5` and `y = 3` and need to add the `y`'s value to `x` value, all what I need is these steps:
1- Create variable x : `{% with x=5 %}`
2- Create variable y : `{% with y=3 %}`
3- In my *HTML* tags, *say `<h1>`*, write that : `<h1>{{ x|add:y }}</h1>`
4- Close the y's with : `{% endwith %}`
5- Close the x's with : `{% endwith %}`
Hope it works with you, it worked with me.

```
{% with i=3 %}
    {% with x=1 %}
         <h1>{{i|add:x}}</h1> <!-- result is 4 -->
    {% endwith %}
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: The question is about subtraction and your answer is adding values