# Subtracting 2 integers in Django Templates

Tags: python, django

Does any one know how to perform mathematical functions within a Django template? I want to subtract one number from another.

```
{% for person in persons %}
<tr>
    <td>{{ person.birthday|date:"jS M" }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
    <td>Minus this {% now "Y" %} from this {{ person.birthday|date:"Y" }}</td>
    <td>{{ person.address }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948095/variable-subtraction-in-django-templates

Answer (score 2):

Don't try and do this in the template. Either define a method in your `Person` model, or write a custom template filter.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [timesince](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince) filter may do what want.

```
{% with now as today %}
{{ person.birthday|timesince:today }}
{% endwith %}
```

However, you should strongly consider just calculating the value as a method on your `Person` model. The Django template language is weak on these kinds of things for a reason (a good one, IMHO). Keeping logic like this on your model, or calculated in your view and passed in as a context variable, is almost always a better idea.

Lastly, you could always use [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/) to accomplish the fairly simple task of creating your own template tag or filter if what you really want to do is manipulate integers. Again, it is often that simply passing the data in via context or on your object is the better course of action.