# Subtract two values in Django Templates

Tags: django, templates, math, subtraction

I have this kind of code in my template:

```
<TD WIDTH=136 STYLE="border: none; padding: 0in">
    <P ALIGN=RIGHT> {{ counterbill.new_measurement - counterbill.old_measurement }}</P>
</TD>
```

Now i want to subtract counterbill.old_measurement from counterbill.new_measurement.
Does anyone know, how to right this correctly?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948095/variable-subtraction-in-django-templates

Comment: Is the `counterbill` a model instance?

Comment: I counter falsetru question - if it is, you should just add a `measurement_difference` method to the model. And in any case - template is generally not a place to make calculations.

Comment: Yes, counterbill is a model instance.

Comment: Just add a `measurement_difference` method to the model then, and use it in your template - `{{ counterbill.measurement_difference }}`.