# How do minus in django template

Tags: python, django

Whanna do minus in template
try:

```
{{ order.total_price|add:"-"order.shop.delivery_price }}
```

Could not parse the remainder: ' order.shop.delivery_price' from 'order.total_price|add:"-" order.shop.delivery_price'

how i can do minus?
...

Comment: Why don't create a minus template tag?

Comment: You have the answer there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948095/variable-subtraction-in-django-templates ;)

Comment: whanna do rhart without template tags

Comment: You can't do it with the built in filters. You can either write your own, or use a package like `django-mathfilters`. It might be better to keep the logic out of the template entirely -- you could do the subtraction in Python and simplify the template to `{{ order.net_price }}`.

Comment: FYI, "whanna" is not an English word. Please say "I want to" instead.

Comment: kk, i'll do that special for u