# How to subtract two fields in django templates?

Tags: python, django

Before marking as duplicate to numerous other questions on SO, read. I have three fields, `Credit Available`, `Credit Limit` and `Credit Balance`. I'm getting the values for `Credit Limit` and `Credit Balance` from my database. To display `Credit Available`, I want to do `Credit Limit`-`Credit Balance`. I tried doing this from other answers on stackoverflow, but they did not work

```
<tr>
    <td style="text-align:center">{{ credit.credit_limit|add:"-{{credit.credit_balance}}" }}</td>
    <td align="center">{{ credit.credit_limit}}</td>
    <td align="center">{{ credit.credit_balance }}</td>
</tr>
```

Can I do this without writing new template tags or using the mathfilter module?

Answer (score 7):

The correct syntax for adding the limit to the balance is

```
{{ credit.credit_limit|add:credit.credit_balance }}
```

as per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#add.
Unfortunately, putting a minus sign in front of a variable won't work to make it negative.

You could use a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), which would be fairly straightforward. It might look like this:

```
@register.filter(name='subtract')
def subtract(value, arg):
    return value - arg
```

Then in your template (after loading it) it would be:

```
{{ credit.credit_limit|subtract:credit.credit_balance }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative way as I tried to explain here:

[Variable subtraction in django templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948095/variable-subtraction-in-django-templates/51468222#51468222)

I'm sure this method can be applied to your question too.

I'm pretty sure it's still better to go with a custom template helper anyway..
It's also not wrong to add the calculated value to your view / model imo.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty old, but in case anyone is seeing this nowadays you can perform this operation in a `<script>` tag like so:

```
<script>
    function updateBalance() {
        available = Number('{{credit.credit_limit}}') - Number('{{credit.credit_balance}}')
        $('tr').getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML = available.toString()
    }
</script>
```

Essentially we access the Django variable within the function, convert it from a string to a number, perform the operation, and set the inner HTML to the new value as a string. This is less efficient than performing the operation on the Django side, but allows us to perform operations against context variables without custom filters or other libraries. If you had multiple rows in your table that required use of this operation, you would want to iterate over each row and perform the operation on each like:

```
<script>
    function updateTableBalances() {
        var table, tr
        table = document.getElementByTagName("table")
        tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        
        // Loop through our table rows, skipping the first one since that is likely our table headers
        for (i=1; i < tr.length; i==) {
            available = Number('{{credit.credit_limit}}') - Number('{{credit.credit_balance}}')
            tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[0].innerHTML = available.toString()
        }
    }
</script>
```

Hope this helps someone!