# Subtract tags in Django

Tags: django, math, tags

Im been wondering if it is possible to subtract two tags variable in Django something like this, thanks for the help, Below I provided my code which I already used, is there any expert know about the problem?

```
{% for user_information in values.qs %}
<td>({{user_information.amount|floatformat:2|intcomma}} - {{user_information.amount_paid|floatformat:2|intcomma}}) </td>
{% endfor %}
```

> Updated using math filters

```
    {% load mathfilters %}
    {% for user_information in benefeciaries.qs %}
    {% with amount1=user_information.amount amount2=user_information.amount_paid %}    
    <td>answer= {{ amount1|sub:amount2 }}</td> 
   {% endwith %}                
   {% endfor %}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9948180/10860596

Comment: @Biplove Lamichhane I already check this but I think this is not what I'm looking for

Comment: @Biplove Lamichhane Is there any shorcut way to subtract between two tags?

Comment: I don't think so. Still you can search for concatenation.

Comment: what Biplove linked seems a viable solution for you. either use django-mathfilters or creating custom template tag as mentioned in the link

Comment: @ha-neul Yes I think Im gonna use mathfilters can you check above if this is the correct way to apply mathfilters? thanks in advance

Comment: I add as an answer for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948095/variable-subtraction-in-django-templates/9948180#9948180)has some good answers, you can either use custom template tag or use mathfilters.

To use mathfilters:
1.

```
$ pip install django-mathfilters
```

2. add `mathfilters` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`.
3. In your template:

```
{% load mathfilters %}
 
    {% with amount1=user_information.amount amount2= 
    user_information.amount_paid %}    

   <li>answer= {{ amount1|sub:amount2 }}</li> 
   {% endwith %}
```

**Update 2** After op showed the full lengthy html template.

The problem is that you are writing {for ...} twice. In the beginning of your html file, you already have {for... } so with {% load mathfilters %} you do not need to add that again.

Comment: thanks for your response but Im getting this error  - Invalid block tag on line 210: 'endwith', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Comment: can you try put {% load math filters %} below {% for }?

Comment: I already tried but the result is the same :/

Comment: sorry It seems I had several typos on top. need to remove {{}} under {% with }

Comment: thanks for your concern and response but I tried the error is always the same

Comment: Hi, did you copy my code exactly? because I just tried in my own project, and it works just fine.

Comment: Could you copy-paste my code to your html file? Note that you should not have {{}} inside of {% with }. It works in my own project. Please check again.

Comment: yes I already tried but the result is always the same you can check the updated code above

Comment: I think it is most likely because your for statement. where this benefeciaries.qs from? shouln't it be benefeciaries? I updated with my own code in my project. As you can see items are the queryset retruned from views .

Comment: Im using Django-filter that why I used I have .qs but even I removed the for userinformation in beneficiaries.qs the result is the same and I don't know why since theres no lacking endpoint of the code you've provided , I upload my all table above you can check it and below you can find mathfilters :/

Comment: you are writing {for loop again. You have one on top of your html file. So you do not need that again in yoru mathfilters logic

Comment: I am going to clean up my answer, so later other people will benefit.