# How to get difference between two dates as a integer inside Django templates

Tags: python, django, date, datetime, django-templates

I have list of two dates: `['2022-07-11', '2022-07-19']` and have to calculate difference between them as a `int` value: `8` inside `Django templates`.
I tried with:

```
{% with value1=date.value.1 value0=date.value.0 %}
   <h3>{{ value1-value0 }}</h3>
{% endwith %}
```

Error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '-value0' from 'value1-value0'
```

I also tried with `timesince` and `timeuntil`still no result

Any way to get just get difference between as a `int`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9948180/183910

Answer (score 1):

That kind of calculations are better moved outside template to [Custom tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/).

In template:

```
{{ date.value.1|minus_date=date.value.0 }}
```

Then in custom_tags.py (or whatever you will name your file):

```
@register.filter(name='minus_date')
def minus_date(first_date, second_date):
    # calculate in classic Python way
    return result
```